# Printing multiple maps in the same pdf

Tags: leaflet, printing, maps

Im using leaflet, Is there a plugin that allows it to print more than one map in the same pdf like this example .[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Leaflet-easyprint](https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint) to generate printable pngs.